# инкремент префиксный

Tags: c++, инкремент

Почему здесь получается 9 а не 6?

```
int x = 1, a;
a = ++x*++x;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь вообще UB. Если значение переменной изменяется, то использовать её более одного раза в выражении запрещено (кроме явно оговоренных случаев).

Вероятно, в твоём случае вычислилось как-то так:

```
a = (++x, ++x, x*x);
```